# Problems installing an LSI MegaRAID 9341-8i in Dell t5810 workstation

Tags: raid, dell-precision, workstation, megaraid

I have been working on building a home server for learning purposes and also to keep my family media stuff. I decided to go with a [Dell Precision T5810](https://www.dell.com/support/home/gy/en/gybsdt1/product-support/product/precision-t5810-workstation/docs) workstation as I got it cheap, for only $200; also, it is a very silent machine that I can keep in my small apartment.

Everything has been good so far until I bought this [LSI MegaRAID 9341-8i](https://www.broadcom.com/products/storage/raid-controllers/megaraid-sas-9341-8i) RAID controller from eBay, which apparently is in new conditions (looks like new and the posting said it was new). When I install it in my machine, it only boots until the Dell screen and does nothing else from there, I have waited up to 10 minutes but nothing.

So far I disabled the integrated RAID controller, also made sure it was installed in a PCI 3.0 x16 port. Also tried booting with all my drives disconnected, except for the M2.NVME

My workstation has the following specs:

Dell Precision T5810
Intel Xeon E5-2650 v3 2.30GHz 10 Core Processor (LGA2011-3)
64GB PC4-2400T Registered DIMM modules (2x32GB)
Samsung 970 EVO 500GB M.2 NVMe
Western Digital Green 2TB HDD
Samsung 860 EVO 1TB SSD

I bought this RAID controller but it was listed in the specs for this machine as a compatible hardware.

https://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell-Precision-Tower-5000-Series-5810-Spec-Sheet.pdf

I know RAID is dead, well I learned that after buying the controller. But I plan on only using it as dumb HBA to release the storage management load from the main board; and also I spent $169 on it, so I just don't want to throw it away :-(

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read over this and then poke about your BIOS options and such. Try with the controller connected and press the hot key at boot up when your first restart it, when it is starting up at the restart, press F12 or perhaps some other hot key to get to these BIOS options, and then from there find the controller and initialize it and then you should be able to see the disks and carve up accordingly. At least in a nut shell it should work like that essentially, good luck!!.....

Comment: Here's the post actually, I forgot to attache the URL.... https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln309467/management-and-configuration-of-raid-arrays-on-lsi-megaraid-9361-8i-9440-9460-and-9341-raid-controllers?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

So I retried after several months and a new motherboard firmware. It seems that the firmware update made the trick as it was so easy to install the card now. Previously the card only worked when the BIOS was set to legacy instead of UEFI.